# Create disk image from a remote system

Tags: backup, ssh, remote, iso-image

I want to backup a disk from a remote system, but the remote system itself has not enough space available. Now I want to use `dd`and pipe the output through `ssh`, but I can't figure out how to do it. I read several sources on the web, but I'm stuck now.

Can someone please point me to a good resource or write down the command line with explanations?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I figured it out:

```
ssh target_address dd if=remotefile | dd of=localfile
```

If you fill out the placeholders, you get something like this:

```
ssh -C username@192.168.1.123 "dd if=/dev/sda" | dd of=mydiskimage.img
```

Comment: there is a missing `dd` in the second command

Comment: @Tshepang Can you give the complete command with the `dd` that is missing?

Comment: `ssh -C username@192.168.1.123 dd if=/dev/sda | dd of=mydiskimage.img`